# Django render table slow loading

Tags: python, django, performance, loading

I need to render data table, with  200 rows. I have models with lot of methods. I need to render output from these methods, but it's very slow (3-6 seconds). Is there any way to do it faster? Model methods looking for foreign keys, and many to many relationships.

Comment: for FK optimization take a look at [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: hi, thanks for your fast reply, now i tring use django-tables2 its little bit faster, but still so slow, i will try using select_related and prefetch_related

Comment: You could also check if you need to show them upfront. You could load let's say 10 and then load the rest via ajax.